# Select an option with the requests module in Python?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, python-requests, bots

So far I've only seen questions about filling in an HTML text tag with the "name" attribute, but what about forms with option tags? For example, say I want a bot to fill out a form, and a form may have a date (for example, month of birth). How would I select a specific option tag for the month with the requests module?

Comment: Add some context, every site is different so what you are asking is pretty broad, also requests does not parse the html, it retrieves it, if you want to parse the option tag you would need something like lxml or bs4

Comment: Try to inspect the requests being made by the webpage when making the POST after selecting the options and filling other form fields. Then, try to replicate the request using `python-requests`